# vue.js $HTTP.GET return NULL PHP RESPONSE

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I'm trying to consume an API and the $ http.get only returns NULL. I call a PHP that returns a json

What nonsense am I doing?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.7/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue.resource/1.0.3/vue-  resource.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">{{cervejarias}}</div>


new Vue({
el:'#beerApp',

data:{
cervejarias: null
},
methods:{
getChamados: function(){
    this.$http.get('listar_cervejarias.php').then(function(response){
        this.cervejarias = response.data;
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error.statusText);
    });
 }
},
 mounted: function () {
 this.getChamados();
 }


  });
```

Comment: Could you do `console.log(response.data)` into the promise ? And post output here ?

Comment: HI

[Object { Id="50630",  Id_cadastro="61693",  Operador=""}]

Comment: If json 
[{"Id":"50630","Operador":"","Id_cadastro":"61693"}]
Not WORK

{"Id":"50630","Operador":"","Id_cadastro":"61693"}
Work

My Php return 
[{"Id":"50630","Operador":"","Id_cadastro":"61693"}]

Comment: Okay, what if you change this line `this.cervejarias = response.data;` to this `this.cervejarias = response.json();`

Comment: nothing

n { promise=Promise,  context=undefined,  bind=function(),  mais...}

Comment: I'm not sure, but this line doesn't looks right `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue.resource/1.0.3/vue-  resource.min.js"></script>` there are some extra spacing.But not sure it that present on real app.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the PHP script?

Comment: Thanks, changed  this.cervejarias = response.data;  per this.cervejarias = response.body; worked

Answer (score -1):

Consider adding:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

To your PHP pages.